# Compare timestamps in postgresql returning hours:minutes exclude weekends

Tags: postgresql

Trying to create a report where I compare two timestamp and get the hours:minutes difference, while excluding the weekends.

For example:

`(select CONCAT((extract(hours from cad.pre_draw_complete - cad.pre_draw_start)  + extract(days from cad.pre_draw_complete - cad.pre_draw_start) * 24::text, ':', extract(mins from cad.pre_draw_complete - cad.pre_draw_start)::text)) as "Predraw duration"`

This returns a timestamp difference with the hours:minutes. How would I filter out the weekends when I compare them? I am using Postgres 9.1

Comment: I'd suggest: count weekends between the two days, multiply by 24, subtract.

Comment: I can't see how your formula skips weekends. Anyhow, you'd have to define what you mean by weekend. Most western countries have Sat-Sun weekend, from midnight to midnight. Some countries have Fri-Sat weekend and several countries only one day (Fri, Sat or Sun depending on major religion there).

Comment: That is my question. How do I find the weekend days when I am calculating the time differences and subtract the weekend hours (Saturday and Sunday) from the total hours.

Comment: If the time ends on Sunday afternoon, should if count as if it ended midnight between Fri and Sat? Give us some example timestamps and what answers you expect to have.